# Log.d problems in kotlin (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

So I am trying to create the flappy bird game using kotlin language, and I ran into a problem with the log.d command. Here is my MainActivity.kt code:

```
package com.example.flappybird

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.ImageButton
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val Tag = "MainActivity"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val ImageButton: ImageButton = findViewById(R.id.btnPlay)
        ImageButton.setOnClickListener(
            Log.d(Tag)
        )
    }
}
```

Under the Log.d(Tag) line, I get this error:

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
d(String?, String) defined in android.util.Log
d(String?, String?, Throwable?) defined in android.util.Log
```

Now, here is my PlayThread.kt code, which is a class:

```
package Thread

    import Model.BackgroundImage
    import android.content.res.Resources
    import android.graphics.Canvas
    import android.util.Log
    import android.view.SurfaceHolder
    
    
    class PlayThread : Thread {
    
        private val TAG : String = "PlayThread"
        private var holder : SurfaceHolder
        private var resources : Resources
        private var isRunning : Boolean = false  //flag run or stop
        private val FPS : Int = (1000.0/60.0).toInt()  //time per frame for 60 fps
        private val backgroundImage = BackgroundImage() //object model
        private var startTime : Long = 0
        private var frameTime : Long = 0
    
    
    
        constructor(holder: SurfaceHolder, resources: Resources) {
            this.holder = holder
            this.resources = resources
            isRunning = true
        }
    
        override fun run() {
            Log.d(TAG, msg: "Thread Started")
            while(isRunning) {
                if (holder == null) return
                startTime = System.nanoTime()
                val canvas = holder.lockCanvas()
                if (!canvas) {
                    try{
                        synchronized(holder) {
                            render(canvas)
                        }
    
                    }
                finally {
                    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas)
    
                }
                }
                }
    
            }
```

I get this error on the Log.d(TAG, msg: "Thread Started") line:

```
Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)
```

I dont know how to fix these, so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `Log.d(TAG, "msg: Thread Started")`

Comment: There is no version of the `d` function that takes just a `tag`. You also have to have a message. If you want to label the parameter, the correct syntax is `msg =` not `msg:`

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

`Log.d(TAG, msg = "Thread Started")`
instead of:

`Log.d(TAG, msg: "Thread Started")`

Comment: named parameter in method is message not msg.

Comment: Named parameters are `tag` and `msg` and `tr` if there is exception to log.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
Log.d(Tag)
```

With

```
Log.d(Tag, " Some log message")
```

This

```
Log.d(TAG, msg: "Thread Started")
```

With

```
Log.d(TAG, "msg: Thread Started")
//Or
Log.d(TAG, msg="Thread Started")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static final String TAG=" Activity";


  val ImageButton:ImageButton = ImageButton(context)
        ImageButton.setOnClickListener{
            Log.d(TAG,"Hello World")
        }
```

This will make it work you have used a method that is not available by Android